# Xamarin - Resource.X does not contain a definition for Y

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-resources

I created a basic SQLite Xamarin Android application using the following tutorial:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-sqlite-database/.

I used almost the same code from the site, but I modified it to suit my needs.

However, the app is not building, the errors I get are:

- Error    CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'add_date_input'
- Error    CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'add_save'
- Error    CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Main'
- Error    CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'AddReminder'

and so on (all errors of same type)...

My main.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addReminder" />
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/reminder_listview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RemindersDBModel;
using RemindersDBHelper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RemindifyListViewAdapter;
using System;
using Android;

namespace ReminderMain
{
    [Activity(Label = "Reminder", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button addReminderBtn;
        ListView listView;
        List<DBModel> listSource = new List<DBModel>();
        DBHelper db;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            db = new DBHelper();
            db.createDatabase();

            addReminderBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addReminder);
            addReminderBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(AddReminderActivity));
            };

            listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;

            loadReminders();
        }

        private void loadReminders()
        {
            listSource = db.selectTable();
            var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, listSource);
            listView.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

What have I tried till now:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Deleting contents of "Resource.Designer.cs"
- Reinstalling Android SDKs
- Adding `<AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
  <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>` to the Reminder.csproj

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's compiler sometimes will make some mistakes.

Try to delete the bin and obj folder, and restart your VS.

Comment: What about creating  a new project?

Comment: I created a new project but I just copied files from the old one and it did not work. I will probably create a completly new project without using old files as I'm running out of options.

Comment: Hi,@SomeGuy Would you mind upload your origin project on the github? I want to have a try.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your answer as the solution as it helped me in few errors I got later.